# Hola, tengo una duda sobre un método String en java, estoy intentando retornar un valor mas de una

Tags: java

tengo el siguiente método en java

```
public String empezarJuego(boolean onGame){
        this.onGame = onGame;
        NaveEspacial nv00 = new NaveEspacial();
        nv00 = naveEspacial;
        for(int i =0 ; i < 5; i++){
            if(i == 4){
                break;
            }
            return naveEspacial.toString();
        }
        //este return no hace nada ya que primero entra al for y retorna ahí
        return " ";
    }
```

estoy intentando retornar la funcion toString del objeto NaveEspacial mas de una vez,  pero al instanciar el objeto naveEspacial y llamar a la funcion empezarJuego en el programa principal de esta forma:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        NaveEspacial nv00 = new NaveEspacial();

        Asteroide a00 = new Asteroide();
        //System.out.println(a00);

        Ventana ventana = new Ventana(a00, nv00);
        ventana.empezarJuego(true);
        System.out.println( ventana.empezarJuego(true)); 
    }
```

solo retorna los datos 1 sola vez, ya intente con un while y con un do(){}while(); si en vez de poner return pongo un println funciona, pero un requisito del programa es que dentro de las clases esta prohibido usar funciones para imprimir y leer.

Comment: los datos de la nave iran cambiando cierto tiempo, si solo retorno una vez obtendre los datos del inicio, y puede que en el trancurso de la ejecución la nave se mueva y choque con algo (es parte del programa), por eso necesito varias veces los string, para ir actualizando los datos.

Comment: Deberías definir de otro modo el flujo del programa, toda función en la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación termina en cuanto llega a una sentencia con `return`. Si quieres tener distintos valores Strings, pídelos a la nave directamente.

Comment: Que se supone que haga empezar juego? no te falta una funcion que te diga el estado a cada momento?

Comment: Ese metodo no tiene sentido, en la primera iteracion de ese bucle, la funcion finalizara...

Comment: De acuerdo con el comentario de @MrDave1999 David, tienes un error de concepcion en la logica que estas intentando ejecutar. Si quieres imprimir por cada iteracion del `for` no debes darle ' return' dentro del for porque apenas se ejecute te va a salir del método. Tendrías que invocar la sentencia de impresión `System.out.println` dentro del  `for` o si lo que desea es que el método `empezarJuego` devuelva los valores concatenados debe usar una variable para acumular la concatenación dentro del método `empezarJuego` antes de ejecutar la sentencia return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la manera seria retornar un array de strings en lugar de un solo string

el codigo seria asi:

```
public String[] empezarJuego(boolean onGame){
        this.onGame = onGame;
        NaveEspacial nv00 = new NaveEspacial();
        nv00 = naveEspacial;

        String[] valores = new String[5];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
            if(i == 4){
                break;
            }
            
            valores[i] = naveEspacial.toString();
        }
        
        return valores;
    }
```

luego solo debes recorrer el array para obtener cada valor por separado